# Facebook Graph API Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I've spent the several hours reading posts here, and following links (many of them dead) to developer.facebook.com.

How can I display my most recent FB post on my external website?  I can do this by manually updating access token every couple of hours.  Or I could ask my website visitors to log into facebook when they visit my website.  Obviously neither is a desirable solution.

The best I've been able to find is Facebook's offline-access-removal instructions https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token.  In order to proceed, it seems I need an App ID.  I'm making quite a few assumptions that this is the right approach.  Can anyone explicitly confirm that this effort will eventually work?  Or do I need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You extend a short lived access-token for a long lived access token. The only person that needs to login is the user you want the data from. Then you save the `access_token` to a database with the expiry and retrieve when needed for everyone else. In short steps

- Load your SQL with the access_token structure
- Create a configuration file for the database
- Create helper functions for database actions such as connecting and querying
- Load the Facebook SDK for the administration view page (this is where you want the login action to get the access_token)
- Update the database with access_token retrieved
- Use the front end to select the access_token from the database

There is a [detailed workout for a page](http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/getting-your-facebook-page-on-your-website-with-access-tokens/) display though it wouldn't be that hard to modify it for long lived access tokens

An example can be found at https://github.com/phwd/hellopageposts

Source: http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/getting-your-facebook-page-on-your-website-with-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like I'm progressing faster than I expected.  I hope to post again before too long.

Answer (score 0):

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ follow all the steps.
2. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

The stumbling block for me is that the first page gives you sample scripts (PHP and Javascript), whereas the second page is the basic REST API.  I used curl, and will probably create a shell script when my access token expires in 60 days.  Someone with more cut&paste confidence than I have could do the whole thing with a browser.