# Facebook App Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

This is a follow-up question to one I posted earlier: [Facebook Graph API Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754468/).
I successfully generated a 60 day app token.  But my troubles are not over...

I've been able to isolate my problem using the Graph API Explorer,
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed.  When I type in my transient access code, I get the complete list.  When I type in my app access code, I only get one entry.  One that's not particularly recent, and its permission values don't seem any different than the other entries.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks again.

Jim Schueler

Answer (score 0):

Requesting `/me` with an app access token should give only an error message, because without a user access token the API can’t figure out who “me” is supposed to be.

Use `/userid` in those cases instead.

Comment: I believe that Facebook does, in fact, associate my app access token with my userid.  If I explicitly use my userid instead of the alias "me", the problem remains exactly the same.

Comment: No, app access tokens are not associated with any user id. Using an app access token to request `/me` only results in an OAuthException saying, _“"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."”_

Comment: Interesting discussion.  But- how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

RTFM.

The Scope needs to include 'read_stream' which is not a property of the app but a property of the access code.